# Problem with font after upgrading to MacTeX 2013

Tags: fonts, mactex, updating

I got a problem after upgrading to MacTeX 2013 today. When I try to produce a pdf file with pdflatex I get an error like this:

```
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for pfrr8r. mktexpk: perhaps pfrr8r is
missing from the map file
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log. ** WARNING ** Could not locate
a virtual/physical font for TFM "pfrr8r"...
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pfr}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Something goes wrong when I add \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pfr}.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post an MWE (minimum working example) that generates the problem you're encountering. The information you've provided so far doesn't really permit making any kind of specific diagnosis of the problem.

Comment: Is the `pfr` font installed in your local `texmf` folder?

Comment: Well, it is installed in my `texmf-local` folder under `/usr/local/texlive/`. But I don't see any `texmf` folder in my new 2013 folder under `/usr/local/textlive/`, though I think there should be one since there is one for 2012. Can I just copy & paste `texmf` from 2012 to 2013?

Comment: Hmm. That should have worked, I think. Don't copy and paste from one year to another.  In a terminal window, what does `kpsewhich updmap.cfg` return? P.S. If you preface your comment with @AlanMunn I'll be notified of the new comment.

Comment: @AlanMunn It returns `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg`.

Comment: @universalis ***Don't*** copy over the old `texmf` folder to the new `/usr/local/texlive/2013`; you'd end up with an unstable TeX system. The fonts should still be in `texmf-local`. What does `kpsewhich --all updmap.cfg` say?

Comment: @universalis *Where* precisely `pfrr8r.tfm` was stored?

Comment: @AlanMunn It still returns `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg`.

Comment: @egreg `pfrr8r.tfm` is in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/frutiger`.

Comment: @universalis And what is `kpsewhich pfrr8r.tfm` returning?

Comment: @egreg It returns `/usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/fonts/tfm/frutiger/pfrr8r.tfm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Font map management changed with TeX Live 2012. For fonts residing in `TEXMFLOCAL` (default location `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`) one should have a file called `updmap.cfg` with the pointers to the map files. Its location should be

```
$TEXMFLOCAL/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

which is, if you have a standard distribution,

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

Here's mine:

```
Map mtpro2.map
Map ugm.map
Map zgm.map
Map dayroman.map
Map stix.map
Map lucida.map
```

After creating the file and populating it with the pointers to the desired map files, run

```
sudo mktexlsr
sudo updmap-sys
```

and the business should return in synch.

This assumes you *never* run `updmap` (without the `-sys` suffix).